# How to restructure my multidimensional array and output as json?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I need to create a new array using the following input array, then convert it to a json value.
Can you please help me on this?

```
[options_label] => Color
[options_value] => Array
    (
        [0] => Red
        [1] => Blue
    )
[options_qty] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 20
    )
[options_sub_label_0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sizes
    )
[options_sub_value_0] => Array
    (
        [0] => S
        [1] => M
    )
[options_sub_qty_0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 6
    )
[options_sub_label_1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sizes
    )
[options_sub_value_1] => Array
    (
        [0] => M
        [1] => L
    )
[options_sub_qty_1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 12
    )
```

This is the json that I need to generate:

```
{
    "Color":{
        "Red":{
            "Quantity": "10",
            "Sizes":{
                "S": "4",
                "M": "6"
            }
        },
        "Blue":{
            "Quantity": "20",
            "Sizes":{
                "S": "8",
                "M": "12"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
$array=[
    'options_label'=>'Color',
    'options_value'=>['Red','Blue'],
    'options_qty'=>[10,20],
    'options_sub_label_0'=>['Sizes'],
    'options_sub_value_0'=>['S','M'],
    'options_sub_qty_0'=>[4,6],
    'options_sub_label_1'=>['Sizes'],
    'options_sub_value_1'=>['M','L'],
    'options_sub_qty_1'=>[8,12]
    ];
foreach($array['options_value'] as $k=>$v){
    $result[$array['options_label']][$v]=[
        "Quantity"=>$array['options_qty'][$k],
        $array["options_sub_label_$k"][0]=>array_combine($array["options_sub_value_$k"],$array["options_sub_qty_$k"])
    ];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Output:

```
{"Color":{"Red":{"Quantity":10,"Sizes":{"S":4,"M":6}},"Blue":{"Quantity":20,"Sizes":{"M":8,"L":12}}}}
```

The first thing that you must do is generate a new array from your input array of arrays.  The only minor tricky part is to use the indexes/keys from `options_value` to correctly access the `_sub_` elements.

Because the `options_sub_label_`'s only have one element, it is accessed by `0`.
`options_sub_value_` and `options_sub_qty_` are best joined together using [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

Answer (score 1):

you can do this :

```
<?php

$newArray = array(
    "option1" => $array1,
    "option2" => $array2,
    "option3" => $array3
    );

echo(json_encode($newArray));

?>
```

that is how to simply way to create an single array from some arrays.hope it'll helps you